# OAuth: new login-flow?

Tags: facebook, facebook-oauth

I noticed that the login-flow seems to have changed recently? Our desktop app requests extended permissions with this login-url:

```
https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth/?response_type=token&display=popup&scope=user_about_me,user_hometown,user_likes,user_location,read_stream,publish_actions,offline_access,read_mailbox,manage_pages,read_page_mailboxes&client_id=***&redirect_uri=https://www.facebook.com/connect/login_success.html
```

Facebook now seems to be sending additional stuff before the login_success-URL, like this:

```
https://www.facebook.com/v2.3/dialog/oauth?redirect_uri=http://www.facebook.com/connect/login_success.html&display=popup&scope=user_about_me,user_hometown,user_likes,user_location,read_stream,publish_actions,offline_access,read_mailbox,manage_pages,read_page_mailboxes&response_type=token&client_id=***&ret=login&ext=1428669119&hash=AeZzsa4rZm5pQOtL
```

This is new, isn't it? Is it now v2.3 per default? But we currently use v2.2. Is there any possibility to have the login-flow of a few weeks ago? I tried

*...www.facebook.com/**v2.2**/dialog...*

but it didn't change anything.

Would it be a problem to log in with v2.3 and then use v2.2 for fetching posts etc?

Where can I find information about this new behaviour?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Would it be a problem to log in with v2.3 and then use v2.2 for fetching posts etc?

**No**, it shouldn't be a problem. You could also validate the applied version of the *response* the API returned in the `'facebook-api-version' HTTP header`.

As for your first question, you could supply a version to your login dialog and Facebook will respect that version as mentioned here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/versions#dialogs

If you are facing a different behavior and believe this might be a bug, you can report it here: https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/

Comment: I have a theory of what happened: I received this unexpected login-flow when I used a newly created App (created after March 25th, after introduction of v2.3). I wasn't aware of this. Until then, I had always used an App created in Feb. 2015. I guess this new App **must** use v2.3 then? Could this be an explanation?

Comment: I believe so. You could load the graph api explorer, choose the app from the dropdown, and check the min. version available in the versions dropdown.

Answer (score 1):

Facebook also changed the access_token format from URL encoded to JSON.

> [Oauth Access Token] Format - The response format of https://www.facebook.com/v2.3/oauth/access_token returned when you exchange a code for an access_token now return valid JSON instead of being URL encoded. The new format of this response is {“access_token”: , “token_type”:, “expires_in”:}. We made this update to be compliant with section 5.1 of RFC 6749.

Source: FB v2.3 changelog: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/changelog